# ERROR: Virtual Raspbian on Qemu in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, qemu, arm, assembly

I am trying to emulate Raspberry-pi/Raspbian with QEMU on my linux subsystem. I followed this [link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=37386#p311360) and did the following steps

```
$ mkdir ~/qemu_vms/
Download/copy Raspbian Wheezy to ~/qemu_vms/
Download kernel-qemu to ~/qemu_vms/
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-system
$ file ~/qemu_vms/2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian.img
From the output of the file command, take the partition 2 'startsector' value an multiply by 512, and use this figure as the offset value in the mount command below.
$ sudo mount ~/qemu_vms/2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian.img -o offset=62914560 /mnt
$ sudo nano /mnt/etc/ld.so.preload
Comment out the line in the file (use a # as the first character of the line) and save the file (CTRL+X, then "Y" for yes).
$ sudo umount ~/qemu_vms/2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian.img /mnt
```

When i ran last command in the above commands, my output was

```
umount: /mnt: not mounted.
```

What does this mean? Anyways, thinking i was on the right track, I proceeded and did the following steps

```
$ cd ~/qemu_vms/
$ qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda ~/qemu_vms/2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian.img -redir tcp:5022::22
```

but instead of QEMU giving me a root shell, I got an error with following output

```
qemu-system-arm: -redir: invalid option
```

Where exactly am I making a mistake and how can I complete this process successfully?

Incase this process depends on my Linux subsystem, here is the my ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

What i currently have in the folder `qemu_vms` are `2013-02-09-wheezy-raspbian.img` and `kernel-qemu` which i got from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8u93xblz1v1ly0/kernel-qemu?dl=0)

It would be great if someone could provide a solution to the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that awful ancient way with arm1176, versatilefb, only 256 Mb RAM, a single core, custom ancient kernel and software, etc. Qemu now support a **raspi2** machine, which has USB, 1GiB RAM, 4 cores (and Qemu spreads their load to physical cores when runs emulation). It runs unmodified recent versions of mainstream Raspberry Pi OS officially distributed by Raspberry Pi Foundation. That isn't well documented, but I managed to find out a way to run such machine.

Here is command line I use:

```
screen -mS raspi2 qemu-system-arm \
    -M raspi2 \
    -drive file=2020-12-02-raspios-buster-armhf-full.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=sd,discard=unmap,detect-zeroes=unmap \
    -append "console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait rw dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_enable=0" \
    -kernel boot/kernel7.img \
    -dtb boot/bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb \
    -vnc :1 \
    -monitor stdio \
    -name raspi2 \
    -device usb-tablet -device usb-kbd \
    -device usb-net,netdev=mytap6,mac=02:ca:fe:f0:0e:01 \
    -netdev tap,id=mytap6,ifname=tap6,script=no,downscript=no
```

This works with raw SD card images, but you need to expand your image for it to have a size to be an exact power of 2; this could be done with `qemu-img`. The image file name reflects the particular version I started with: `2020-12-02-raspios-buster-armhf-full`; I also successfully tried a "lite" version. I converted that image to `qcow2` format so save space (so it has 3 GiB instead of 8 and I can also apply qcow2 compression).

Also, you need to extract boot directory from SD image. You'll need to do that each time after kernel update (or any packet that writes to `/boot` partition). In my case of `qcow2` disk format, the easiest way is to connect it to `/dev/nbd0` with `qemu-nbd`, then mount its partitions as usual. Always **stop VM before connecting NBD** and **disconnect NBD before starting VM** again. I've successfully had updated kernel since initial configuration.

`tap6` is a virtual tap adapter set owned by my user ID, so I run qemu from unprivileged user. It is the part of my bridge with physical NIC, so this virtual Raspberry Pi appears in the LAN along with my computer, successfully receives an address from DHCP server and so on.

I put that into the script `run.sh` to not bother to construct command line each time. I use `screen` to be able to detach it from the terminal. To connect to this RasPi screen I run `vncviewer localhost:1`. So this command can be run, say, remotely via SSH and the VNC can be tunneled via same SSH.

**Beware: it's slow even on realtively fast workstation.** For example, it boots to full GUI in approximately 10 minutes on i5-3470. I believe this is because of huge emulation overhead. The kernel boot log:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.83-v7+ (dom@buildbot) (gcc version 8.4.0 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1)) #1379 SMP Mon Dec 14 13:08:57 GMT 2020
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x38000000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 245760
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2160 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 245760 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 20 pages/cpu s49740 r8192 d23988 u81920
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s49740 r8192 d23988 u81920 alloc=20*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 243600
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait rw dwc_otg.fiq_fsm_enable=0
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 892624K/983040K available (9216K kernel code, 698K rwdata, 2608K rodata, 1024K init, 827K bss, 24880K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `-redir` argument is the error, you may want to try an alternative syntax to get host-guest portforwarding working. [This section of the qemu docs](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#How_to_get_SSH_access_to_a_guest) recommends doing:

```bsh
-device e1000,netdev=net0 -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22
```

Instead of:

```
-redir tcp:5022::22
```

---

## Further reading

- [redir option removed from qemu](https://wiki.qemu.org/Features/RemovedFeatures)
- [Using redir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55043135/qemu-system-arm-redir-invalid-option/55045534) did not work for this guy either
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46041082/how-to-replace-qemu-system-redir-command-argument) is a really good post that explains `-device` and `-netdev` and their relationship to `-redir`